# 4*4 Word Square #3

Tags: crosswords, word-square

A word square is a puzzle in which letters can be placed into the grid below so that words are formed both horizontally and vertically. In this puzzle, the same four words are formed in each direction.

[image: the 4*4 grid]

The clues, in no particular order, are as follows:

- Company known for denim-wear.
- 1965 Beatles song.
- Always.
- Formal and respectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solved word square should look like this:

> [image: Solved word square]

With the clues corresponding to the following answers:

> 1965 Beatles song. = **[HELP!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help!_(song))**
>  Always. = **EVER**
>  Company known for denim-wear. = **[LEVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_Strauss_%26_Co.)**
>  Formal and respectable. = **PRIM**

Comment: Congratulations! : ) Any idea how I could do better so I don't get downvotes?

Comment: @PiGuy314 I think it's just the case that you pumped out 3 of these on the same day. Your first two both got positive vote counts, but people get 'puzzle type fatigue', where at first what can seem like a fun/good idea ends up losing its spark purely because people see lots of them and get bored. Try and produce different types of interesting puzzles, don't pigeonhole yourself in one type :) Explore the world of puzzling, try new things, and have fun!